# CoreAnimation jerky with large window

Tags: cocoa, core-animation

I have a very simple CA demo. It creates a layer with content from an image file, and displays that image. When you click in the window, it uses implicit animation to smoothly move the image to the mouse point. This works fine, runs with perfect smoothness. But, as the window gets larger, the smoothness gets less. It's acceptable below about 75% of the screen size. With a maximized window, or in fullscreen mode, it is very rough and jerky.

I'm running OSX 10.5.7 on an intel Mac Mini. It has an intel GMA950 GPU. My screen is 1920 x 1200.

I do not have a drawRect method at all. Everything happens by setting the position property of the CALayer, using implicit animation.

Am I right to suspect that the hardware is at fault here?

Neil Baylis

Answer (score 0):

Your Hardware is just fine and capable - the implementation is lacking.

You are not allowed to animate or even touch the Position Property. That property is handled by the view if layer-backed. Not you. And re-calculated on numerous occasion. So if you begin to animate and change that property there are going to be trouble. At least according to Apple...

Here an Excerpt

According to Apple -> 
To animate changes to a layer-backed view in OS X, it is best to use the interfaces of the view itself. You should rarely, if ever, directly modify the layer that is attached to one of your layer-backed NSView objects. AppKit is responsible for creating and configuring those layer objects and for managing them while your app is running. Modifying the layer could cause it to get out of sync with the view object and could lead to unexpected results. For layer-backed views, your code must absolutely not modify any the following properties of the layer object:
    •   anchorPoint
    •   bounds
    •   compositingFilter
    •   filters
    •   frame
    •   geometryFlipped
    •   hidden
    •   position
    •   shadowColor
    •   shadowOffset
    •   shadowOpacity
    •   shadowRadius
    •   transform